# A way to group variables in a container for collective actions and maintain individual accessibility

Tags: java, variables

I have multiple variables:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
//...
int z = 25;
```

Is there an efficient way to perform actions on all of them, or selectively? And at the same time each variables can be accessed individually? Like the following, just an imagination:

```
Collection col = new Collection(a...z);   // group all variables

for (int alphabet : col) {                // change value of all variables
    alphabet += 1;
}
System.out.print(a.toString()); // "1"    // individual variable still accessible
System.out.print(z.toString()); // "26"

for (int alphabet : col) {                // reassign all variables
    int newAlphabet = alphabet * -1;
    alphabet = newAlphabet;
}
System.out.print(a.toString()); // "-1"   // individual variable still accessible
System.out.print(z.toString()); // "-26"

col.getIndex(1).set(99);                  // modify variables selectively
System.out.print(b.toString()); // "99"   // individual variable still accessible

c = 0;
System.out.print(
    col.getIndex(2).toString()); // "0"   // value in collection updates with value in variable
```

It is feasible to use Array / ArrayList to do all the above but at the same time I still want to keep the variable name.

Comment: Make the 26 variables fields in a new user defined type. That is how you "group" variables in Java. You define a type.

Comment: How are these values semantically related?  Are they elements of a collection?  If so then you'd want some collection (array-like) type to hold them.  Are they attributes of a combined semantic concept?  If so then they describe fields on a class.  It's not clear what you're asking which doesn't fall into one of these two structures.

Comment: I think that you're putting much too much importance on variable names, which are almost non-existent in compiled code. Focus on references, here, perhaps a `Map<Character, SomeOtherType>`. Otherwise, this looks to possibly be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) type question where you may be better off telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you are trying to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JAVA - store letters and number of letters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981828/java-store-letters-and-number-of-letters-in-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map`:

```java
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    map.put(ch, ch - 'a');

map.keySet().forEach(key -> map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum));   // change value of all variables

System.out.println(map.get('a')); // "1"    // individual variable still accessible
System.out.println(map.get('z')); // "26"

map.keySet().forEach(key -> map.merge(key, -1, (prv, one) -> prv * one));   // reassign all variables

System.out.println(map.get('a')); // "-1"   // individual variable still accessible
System.out.println(map.get('z')); // "-26"

map.put('b', 99);  // modify variables selectively
System.out.println(map.get('b')); // "99"   // individual variable still accessible

map.put('c', 0);
System.out.println(map.get('c')); // "0"    // value in collection updates with value in variable
```

---

I do not know why you want this logic, but I think you should encapsulate it. For this reason, probably a single `Map` is not the best choice. It's better to write a separate class with required logic.

```java
@NoArgsConstructor    
public final class Data {

    private final int[] arr = new int[26];

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = i;
    }

    public int getA() { return arr[getOffs('a')]; }
    public int getB() { return arr[getOffs('b')]; }
    public int getC() { return arr[getOffs('c')]; }
    // other getters
    public int getZ() { return arr[getOffs('z')]; }

    public void setA(int a) { arr[getOffs('a')] = a; }
    public void setB(int b) { arr[getOffs('b')] = b; }
    public void setC(int c) { arr[getOffs('c')] = c; }
    // other setters
    public void setD(int d) { arr[getOffs('d')] = d; }

    public void update(IntFunction<Integer> func) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            arr[i] = func.apply(arr[i]);
    }

    private static int getOffs(char ch) { return Character.toLowerCase(ch) - 'a'; }

}
```

So the client code will look like this:

```java
Data data = new Data();

data.update(val -> val + 1);   // change value of all variables

System.out.println(data.getA()); // "1"    // individual variable still accessible
System.out.println(data.getZ()); // "26"

data.update(val -> val * -1);   // reassign all variables

System.out.println(data.getA()); // "-1"   // individual variable still accessible
System.out.println(data.getZ()); // "-26"

data.setB(99);  // modify variables selectively
System.out.println(data.getB()); // "99"   // individual variable still accessible


data.setC(0);
System.out.println(data.getC()); // "0"    // value in collection updates with value in variable
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... It is feasible to use Array / ArrayList to do all the above but at the same time I still want to keep the variable name."*

There isn't a syntax; you'll have to use a class—or as you mentioned an *array* or *List*.

As someone else has mentioned, you could use a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)* and then use the key as the variable name.

Typically what you're looking for would be part of a *[scripting language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language)*.
*Java* is a *[programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)*, so it doesn't have the shortcut you're looking for.

*[Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language))* has many shortcuts like this.
It *may* have the syntax you're looking for, I am not sure.

Research different types of *scripting languages*, and you may find this exact abstraction.

I believe the easiest way to achieve this would be to store the values within an array.
Subsequently, just create a method for each of the procedures required.

```java
class Values {
    int[] values;

    Values(int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    void set(char letter, int value) {
        switch (letter) {
            case 'a' -> values[0] = value;
            case 'b' -> values[1] = value;
            case 'c' -> values[2] = value;
            // ...
            case 'z' -> values[25];
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    int get(char letter) {
        return switch (letter) {
            case 'a' -> values[0];
            case 'b' -> values[1];
            case 'c' -> values[2];
            // ...
            case 'z' -> values[25];
            default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        };
    }
}
```